# Need help in the fabrication of an UHF power amplifier

Tags: hf, uhf, amplifier, power

I recently decided to conceive a 10W class 446MHz amplifier.

I want to be able to amplify a 100mW signal into a 10W, for that i'm going for a two stages amplifier :

1. SKY65162 to amplify the signal to 1W
2. Then a 2SK3075 to reach 10W approx.

Datasheets :

https://www.mouser.fr/datasheet/2/472/SKYS_S_A0006619433_1-2515303.pdf
https://toshiba.semicon-storage.com/ap-en/semiconductor/product/mosfets/detail.2SK3075.html

The first amplifier is very well documented in the datasheet, but the second is more tricky.
I have this datasheet which describes partly the circuit to make use of the transistor :

[image: Schematic recommended by the manufacturer]
This schematic is supposed to describes the circuit required to function at around 500MHz. I was going to use theses values but I thought i could use some help and some tips from you.

**Question:**

*What length shall be the transmission lines made like resistor on the schematic ?*

**Thanks for your help**

Comment: _**10W class 446MHz amplifier**_ oh... in many, if not all, countries this would not be legal to use. Would you care to explain how you are planning to use this?

Comment: For expérimentation mainly, but I'm not putting aside the many challenges. Power is not a problem for me, I'm allowed 200W

Comment: "Do you have tips to spare?" is more a question for forum, not StackExchange. Do you have a more specific question? if so, please update your post above with that specific question.

Comment: I hope you are also building a nice dummy load for this rig.

Comment: Thank you @jdv you're really helping me out on this one.

Comment: Honestly, this may be more suited for EE.SE anyway -- at least the core question of modifying the application note example for specific frequencies. Motorola seems to publish other stuff that is relevant to that, but I'm no EE and I think you need to be one to not set yourself on RF fire with this project.

Comment: Sorry, Toshiba. I had just been looking at some moto parts.